# Lost my Azure Icon on the VSCODE activity bar

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

I have been using the VSCODE Azure extensions successfully till yesterday.
Yesterday I changed the Azure account (and it says I a logged in)
I also added the azure machine language extension.

Now, I no longer have the Azure Icon on the Activity bar, and I have no idea where to find the logs that say something is going wrong. I don't get any visible errors, and I have tried reboot, and re-install of each of these extensions:

- Azure Account
- Azure App Service
- Azure Database
- Azure Functions
- Azure Machine Learning
- Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Tools
- Azure Storage

All claim to be the latest versions

---

```
VSCODE Version: 1.47.3 (user setup)
Commit: 91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
Date: 2020-07-23T13:12:49.994Z
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked to hover the mouse where the icon should be. Or shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>**Alt**</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (not <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).

Comment: And then you can just drag the Azure tools icon from the top, to the side bar and will show up.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from MSFT in github:

> My first question would be whether it's there but the icon is
> invisible. Have you tried the shortcut (SHIFT+CTRL+A I think, on Mac
> it's SHIFT+CMD+A)? And maybe hover the mouse over where the icon
> should be and see if you get a tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is a little bit different. Since I did not choose "Trust workspace and install" when installing the extensions, Microsoft automatically disable my azure extension. So I uninstalled all azure extensions and install again with "Trust workspace and install"

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I click on Trust Option, Azure Icon appears to me
[image]